# Google's AppEngine - java.nio.BufferOverflowException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

I am playing with Google's AppEngine Java support. I have a fairly simple set of JSP pages, and was looking at the logs today, and saw that I was getting a BufferOverflowException from the following JSP file:

```
<%
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
%>
```

I simplified the file to just this, and I still get the error. Any ideas?

Here is the entire stack trace:

```
/logout.jsp
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(Unknown Source)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcResponseGenerator.addContent(RpcResponseGenerator.java:65)
at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.write(AbstractGenerator.java:624)
at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.write(AbstractGenerator.java:575)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(Unknown Source)
at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$OutputWriter.write(AbstractGenerator.java:883)
at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:116)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:190)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:115)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.access$100(JspFactoryImpl.java:37)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl$PrivilegedReleasePageContext.run(JspFactoryImpl.java:173)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.security.AccessController_.doPrivileged(AccessController_.java:31)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:73)
at org.apache.jsp.logout_jsp._jspService(logout_jsp.java:62)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:94)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:237)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:313)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:506)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:830)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:381)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:125)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:235)
at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:4755)
at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:4753)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.BlockingApplicationHandler.handleRequest(BlockingApplicationHandler.java:24)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:359)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$2.run(Server.java:800)
at com.google.tracing.LocalTraceSpanRunnable.run(LocalTraceSpanRunnable.java:56)
at com.google.tracing.LocalTraceSpanBuilder.internalContinueSpan(LocalTraceSpanBuilder.java:510)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server.startRpc(Server.java:756)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server.processRequest(Server.java:348)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.ServerConnection.messageReceived(ServerConnection.java:459)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcConnection.parseMessages(RpcConnection.java:319)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcConnection.dataReceived(RpcConnection.java:290)
at com.google.net.async.Connection.handleReadEvent(Connection.java:419)
at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.processNetworkEvents(EventDispatcher.java:762)
at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.internalLoop(EventDispatcher.java:207)
at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.loop(EventDispatcher.java:101)
at com.google.net.rpc.RpcService.runUntilServerShutdown(RpcService.java:251)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RpcRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:373)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an internal error. Not much you can do about that, except for filing a bug report and waiting for Google to fix it.

A [possibly related bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1429) has been fixed.

Comment: The JSP originally had a little more too it, but when I saw the error, I decided to edit it down to the as small as I could, and sill get the error.

Answer (score 1):

If that's all your code is, then that's not on  Like Thilo said, file a bug report and wait patiently...